# MySQL confusion about group by. Why is this happening?

Tags: mysql, sql

Why are the three queries so different? According to MySQL documentation, shouldn't they all do the same thing?

```
select cc, max(c) as "Most Official Billingual Count" from (
  select CountryCode as cc, count(*) as c from countrylanguage where isofficial = "T"
  group by cc
) t group by cc
```

Returns multiple rows in this format: CountryCode Official_Language_Count_Blabla

Whereas if I remove one group by...

```
select cc, max(c) as "Most Official Billingual Count" from (
  select CountryCode as cc, count(*) as c from countrylanguage where isofficial = "T"

) t group by cc
```

It returns the first country code along with the total count:
ABW 238

And this:

```
select cc, max(c) as "Most Official Billingual Count" from (
  select CountryCode as cc, count(*) as c from countrylanguage where isofficial = "T"
  group by cc
) t
```

Will return something like this: ABW 4

I am very confused about this whole group by thing.

The inner query

```
  select CountryCode as cc, count(*) as c from countrylanguage where isofficial = "T
```

Should return all countrycodes and count the repeated ones? Right? But it doesn't do that.  It seems like I have to do the first queue to get the desired affect, and its just very confusing for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subquery:

```
select CountryCode as cc, count(*) as c from countrylanguage where isofficial = "T"
```

have no sense unless you're not grouping your records via corresponding criteria. You need to group your records, since `WHERE` clause only indicates selection criteria. See this [clarifying video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rd8iW_9JVp8) (DBMS is Oracle there, but no matter) for understanding `GROUP BY`. Also (I prefer reading), you can find many articles for that, for example, [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-group-by-clause.htm).

Thus, if you need to find `MAX` between counts - you need to combine your groups first via `GROUP BY` in your subquery.

Comment: Thank you, I will watch the video tomorrow when I wake up